Why can't I remote from VMware to PC?
I am trying to do the same thing as @modmoto here:

Remote Desktop Connection with VM not working

Only in my case, I tried to connect to work PC from my VM, setup is like picture below:


I have enable desktop remote on both side.
PC and VM machine can ping each other.
I have turn off firewall on both work PC and VM.
From VM I can use share file from work PC.
I have success use other PC inside work network to remote to work PC via IP 102.168.1.197.
Only I can't telnet or RDP or local teramview from my VM to work PC (I have tried connect via both IP and PC name but not possible).


Does your work network allow incoming RDP connections?  Is there no VPN involved anywhere?

Thank you for reading, i dont really get your question.
1/ As i have mention: I have success use other PC inside work network to remote to work PC, so there is no restrict here.
2/ i'm not setup VPN.

#1 is meaningless.  Your work network could easily have a firewall that blocks all incoming RDP connections from outside the network.  This might be especially likely if your work machines are directly addressable from the Internet without a VPN.  Furthermore, you have not demonstrated at all that this has anything to do with VMware or with virtualization; are you able to connect from your home machine ("PC(Win10Pro)") to your work machine?

Have you checked with the IT support staff designated by your employer?
